# loop through associative array in Javascript

Tags: javascript

Not sure where I am going wrong but the following code seems to list my select option values as 0 - 11 instead of 1 - 12

DYNAMICALLY PRODUCED HTML

```
<select id="Month" name="month"> 
  <option value="0">January</option>
  <option value="1">Feburary</option>
  <option value="2">March</option>
  <option value="3">April</option>
  <option value="4">May</option>
  <option value="5">June</option>
  <option value="6">July</option>
  <option value="7">August</option>
  <option value="8">September</option>
  <option value="9">October</option>
  <option value="10">November</option>
  <option value="11">December</option>
</select>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
var months = new Array();
        months[1]   =   'January';
        months[2]   =   'Feburary';
        months[3]   =   'March';
        months[4]   =   'April';
        months[5]   =   'May';
        months[6]   =   'June';
        months[7]   =   'July';
        months[8]   =   'August';
        months[9]   =   'September';
        months[10]  =   'October';
        months[11]  =   'November';
        months[12]  =   'December';
        for(var i = 0; i<12; i++ ){
           month  = months[i+1];
           option ="<option value='"+i+"'>"+month+"</option>"
           options = options+option;
        }
        $('#month').html(' <select id="' + this.id +'" name="' + this.id + '">'+options+'</select>');
```

Comment: Javascript from 0 upwards not 1 which is why you're seeing 0-11 not 1-12

Comment: You produce ZERO because your `i` is zero. The HTML is outputting exactly what you told it too.

Comment: Javascript does not support Arrays with named indexes (there are no associative arrays) - just as a side node.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change this:

```
option ="<option value='"+(i+1)+"'>"+month+"</option>"
```

Or better yet:

```
for(var i = 1; i<=12; i++ )
```

Answer (score 1):

So change the line

```
option ="<option value='"+i+"'>"+month+"</option>"
```

to

```
option ="<option value='"+(i+1)+"'>"+month+"</option>"
```

Answer (score 0):

In the for loop you are not increasing the value of i in line 1 (i+1). Therefore the loop goes 0-11. Why don't you just loop with

```
for (var i = 1; i < 13; ++i){
}
```